# Is there any boolean true or throw error helper method in java

Tags: java

In Java 8+, is there any helper method which checks if boolean statement is TRUE, ok, otherwise, throw specified error.

Something like:

```
Optional.of(myFalseReturningMethod).orElseThrow(() -> new ValidationException("Check request"));
```

Comment: You could always write one yourself if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
if (!myFalseReturningMethod) throw new ValidationException("Check request");
```

Comment: I think this is the most common way to validate something and throw an Exception in false case and it's very concise and clear

Comment: Absolutely nothing, but if you have handful of validations, too many ifs seems messy.

Comment: Just to dip in ahead of time: If the answer to the stated question is: "Because my style guide forces me to 3-line that (with braces), and I find that a lot of code", the answer is: "A style guide is just a tool. If the tool is not serving your needs, get rid of the tool and find a better one". i.e. update your style guide, this kind of style (braceless) is fine if the single statement is controlflow (throw, return, break, or continue).

Comment: 'too many ifs seems messy' doesn't make much sense. It's less code and fewer AST nodes than your `Optional` example. It's __less__ messy. The fact that you think its more messy probably means your definition of 'messy' is unwieldy.

Comment: @rahuls maybe you should start your question from the original problem, I suppose it could be: "the more elegant way for many checks composition?"

Comment: you can always create the method with this if and throw, and then just call it